# Rails: redirect_to(...) and return vs return redirect_to

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When redirecting in rails 3,

Is `return redirect_to(...)` a valid Rails statement?

I've always just used `redirect_to(...) and return` but I saw a line like the one described above and I was surprised to see that it also worked.

Comment: Aside what was said elsewhere, `redirect_to and return` makes the assumption that `redirect_to` returns something falsy so you would have to know that. I have regularly seen cases where code didn't function as expected because of this. The latter will of course always return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is `return redirect_to(...)` a valid Rails statement?

Yes.

Statement validity is not determined by Rails, it is determined by Ruby. And in Ruby `return something` is perfectly valid.

Comment: Any difference between the two in terms of performing a redirect in rails?

Comment: @turntwo No difference.

Comment: Might be worth noting that in general `return something` returns the value returned by `something` whereas `something and return` returns `nil` if `something` was trueish and doesn't return if `something` was falsy. But I agree that it doesn't make a huge difference in this case, because `redirect_to` will never return falsy.

Comment: I tend to use return redirect_to() when the url I am going to be redirecting the user to is conditional. For example: `return redirect_to() if x` some processing and `redirect_to()` a few lines later.